# iOS8 delete ALAsset

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, ios8

The way from iOS7 no longer works in iOS8

```
[asset setImageData:nil metadata:nil completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {

}];
```

How to delete an asset in iOS8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{

    PHFetchResult * fecthResult = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:@[asset.url] options:nil];
    [PHAssetChangeRequest deleteAssets:fecthResult];

} completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {

    if (error) {
        ...
    }

}];
```